# R: split list of list by element id

Tags: r

I would like to split mylist by id and have the possibility of adding up the product values. I have come across lapply, but unfortunately not managed to find any solution using lapply with aggregate-embedded.

```
list1 = list(id=1 , product=5)
list2 = list(id=1 , product=6)
list2 = list(id=2 , product=5)
list3 = list(id=1 , product=4)
list4 = list(id=3 , product=9)
mylist <- list(list1, list2, list3, list4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `transpose` the `list`, bind the rows and then do the group by 'id'

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
mylist %>% 
   transpose %>% 
   map_df(unlist) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(product = sum(product))
```

---

Or another variation of the above is

```
mylist %>%
    transpose %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    unnest %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(product = sum(product))
```

Answer (score 0):

## You may also use data.table package to do that. The R codes are as bellow:

> library(data.table)
>
> newlist <- lapply(mylist, as.data.table);
> dt <- rbindlist(newlist);
> data.table::dcast(dt, "id~.",value.var = "product", fun = sum)